# Find all modules importing a given module on Hackage

Tags: haskell, hackage

I'd like to find all modules on Hackage which import a given module from a given package. As an example of why this is useful, I'd like to see all modules that import `Language.Haskell.HLint` from the `hlint` package, since I want to deprecate that module but am interested in how it is currently used.

Is there any index (ideally online) tracking such import relationships?

Comment: I want to know what packages (or even modules) use what *individual exports*. That would really help me understand how functions in the libraries I maintain are being used, do I can know how performance matters, and where it likely matters most. If I can get 20% savings on a 1ms operation (your example of something likely not worth the trouble) then I absolutely will do it for library code, but if I know what's on who's hot path, I'll be able to make better decisions.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to cobble something together using https://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse combined with some coarse-grained parsing of the Haskell module imports of the packages you get.

Comment: @dfeuer - you're totally right, that would be a more general question, and strictly more useful.